# Error while running Blink program

Tags: ubuntu, tinyos

I am working in TinyOs in Ubuntu 16.04.
When i run the Blink program, the following error occurs:

```
[INFO] script
        2538 bytes in ROM
          56 bytes in RAM
[INFO] size (toolchain):
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2596       2      56    2654     a5e build/telosb/main.exe
[INFO] generating symbol table
[INFO] generating listing
[INFO] creating ihex file
[INFO] writing TOS image
[INFO] writing TOS buildinfo
[INFO] running the wiring check
<JAVA_HOME>/lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; Use     
-classpath instead.
.Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
../../support/make/Makerules:362: recipe for target 'wiring_check' failed
make: *** [wiring_check] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea about why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by TinyOS build tool chain trying to use Java features which are deprecated in the newest (version 9) Java. You will need to install an older Java JRE version and set your JAVA_HOME to this older version:

- first check your current Java version by typing `java -version` in the terminal. If it isn't version 9 or later, STOP - this probably not the solution you need.
- Go to the [Java download page for older versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html)
- Under 'Java SE' (SE stands for 'standard edition', which is what we need), select an older version. TinyOS officially supports versions 1.4 and 5, but I know that version 7 works okay because that's the version I'm using. Version 8 might also work okay.
- Then under 'Java SE Runtime Environment', select Linux x86 (if you're using Ubuntu 32-bit) or Linux x64 (for 64-bit). You can find out if you have 32 or 64 bit by typing `uname -i` in the terminal. Select the version which ends in '.tar.gz' (.rpm is for other types of Linux). You will need to login using an Oracle account, or sign up if you don't have one.
- Download the .tar.gz file. You can decide where on your system you want to keep this version of Java. You can either just keep it somewhere in your home directory, but by convention we normally keep these kinds of programs in '/usr/local/java'. If you want to keep it there you will have to use `sudo cp`, for example `sudo cp -r jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java` (**your filename may be different**)
- Now you need to extract the files from the compressed .tar.gz file. For example, `sudo tar xvzf /usr/local/java/jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz`
- (Optionally) you can now delete the .
- You need to make sure you have permissions to execute your downloaded java. For example, you could use `chown -R jre-8u73-linux-x64`
- Finally you need to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the location of the java folder you have just made. There are [many ways to do this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). I suggest creating a file in /etc/profile.d directory (called something like java-env.sh) with the following:

  `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre-8u73-linux-x64
  export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin`
- You might also need to tell Ubuntu to use your older version by doing `sudo update-java-alternatives --set /path/to/java/version`
- Open a new terminal window and check that `java -version` now gives you the older version.

A better approach would be to create an isolated development VM environment just for TinyOS, as you don't really want to have old versions of Java on your main machine. You could do this using something like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). How to do this would be too long to answer, check out [their documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html).

Comment: can you tell how to do this?